# Taking out multiple values in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, list, montecarlo

I need to analyse 4 values. However, these 4 values change every time I run the code. I need to run the code 100 times and paste the 4 values in different cells. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
Sub min()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 5
    Cells(i, 14).Value = Array(Cells(5, 12).Value, Cells(6, 12).Value, Cells(5, 13).Value, Cells(6, 13).Value)

Next i
End Sub
```

Every time that i changes, I get 4 different values.

Comment: I always get the value in Cells(5, 12).  one cell cannot hold an array.  It will only hold the first value.  Try `Range(Cells(1, 14), Cells(4, 14)).Value = Application.Transpose(Array(Cells(5, 12).Value, Cells(6, 12).Value, Cells(5, 13).Value, Cells(6, 13).Value))` instead of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the range to match the size of your array.  No need to transpose the Array, it is already in the correct shape.

```
Sub min()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 100
        Cells(i, 14).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(Cells(5, 12).Value, Cells(6, 12).Value, Cells(5, 13).Value, Cells(6, 13).Value)

    Next i
End Sub
```